# Will an async lamdba run every event in the event loop before exiting (without await)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

We have an async Lambda application in Node that publishes metrics to CloudWatch via `PutMetricData`. Since this function is called within non-async functions routinely, and we dont need to handle errors generally or require the return value - we just kick off the request and forget it.

Will an Async Lambda ensure that every call happens (even if the event loop doesnt return a value back to the main thread), or will the event loop stop as soon as the resultant promise of the main function is resolved?

Example:

```
export.handler = async () => {
    doSomethingSynchronous();
}


function doSomethingSynchronous() {
    const value = 1;
    // is this call guaranteed to complete (even if it fails)
    cloudWatch.putMetricData(value);
    return value;
}
```

It makes little sense to make every function asynchronous when we dont need the value or dont need to handle errors.

Edit: Answer I was looking here: https://medium.com/radient-tech-blog/aws-lambda-and-the-node-js-event-loop-864e48fba49

Comment: Partially. Does that mean any function that emits metrics to CloudWatch needs to be asynchronous? Is there any solution to this drawback?

Comment: In particular, look at the second half of the accepted answer. I believe that answers your question.